# how to dynamically add text view to the list view in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, textview, contacts

[image]

I need to add two text view to the list view as shown in figure..what I need is that on the click of contact button  the name and the type of number get automatically into my own list view..I am not been able to add text view to the list view because of that I am only able to see phone's contact list...kindly help me please..thanks in advance..here is the code.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class TestActivity extends ListActivity
{



    private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    //content uri provide directory of people
      Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 

      startActivityForResult(intentContact, PICK_CONTACT);
    }//onCreate

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
    {

      if (requestCode ==PICK_CONTACT)
      { 
          getContactInfo(intent);               
      }



    }//onActivityResult

    protected void getContactInfo(Intent intent)
    {
String name;
       Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);      
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
       {           
           //contains row id
           String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

             name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
         //whether contact list atleast have a single contact or not
           String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

           if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
               hasPhone = "true";
           else
               hasPhone = "false" ;

           if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
           {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) 
            {
              String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }//end
            phones.close();
           }//end

        cursor.close();
       }//end while 


    }//end method
}//end class...........
```

this is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>........


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout> ...
```

Comment: [Pleas have a look at this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List3.html)

Comment: any simpler way or a bit more explanatory example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you have to make custom list, Just Look at this tutorial 
[Android Series: Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) or [MonoDroid - Custom ListAdapter for your ListView](http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview)

Comment: i have read all the examples and have tried couple of though but could not get through..isn't there any simpler way..